# How can you monitor total internet data usage across reboots with site detail?

Tags: network-manager, vnstat

As the question suggests itself, how can I monitor the usage of data on my system. I know about `vnstat` and have already installed on my Ubuntu. What I want is to know if there is any way I can see as to how much data is being used by what website in particular, i.e., what amount of data is being used by Facebook or YouTube?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS or 16.04 LTS you can try [`ntop` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=ntop).

Below is quote of package decription:

> Description-en: display network usage in web browser ntop is a network traffic probe that shows the network usage, similar to what the popular top Unix command does. ntop is based on libpcap and it has been written in a portable way in order to virtually run on every Unix platform and on Win32 as well.
>       ntop users can use a web browser to navigate through ntop (that acts as a web server) traffic information and get a dump of the network status. In the latter case, ntop can be seen as a simple RMON-like agent with an embedded web interface.
>   The use of:
>
> - a web interface
> - limited configuration and administration via the web interface
> - reduced CPU and memory usage (they vary according to network size    and traffic) make ntop easy to use and suitable for monitoring various kind of networks.
>      .
>      This package contains the ntop daemon.

You can install the package with

```
sudo apt install ntop
```

---

Also you can try newer version known as NtopNG and [packaged as `ntopng`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=ntopng).

> Description-en: High-Speed Web-based Traffic Analysis and Flow Collection Tool
>    ntopng is the next generation version of the original ntop, a network
>    traffic probe that shows the network usage, similar to what the popular
>    top Unix command does. ntop is based on libpcap and it has been written
>    in a portable way in order to virtually run on every Unix platform,
>    MacOSX and on Win32 as well.
>    ntopng users can use a web browser to navigate through ntop (that acts as a web server) traffic information and get a dump of the network status. In the atter case, ntop can be seen as a simple RMON-like agent with an embedded web interface.
>
> The use of:
>
> - a web interface
> - limited configuration and administration via the web interface
> - reduced CPU and memory usage (they vary according to network size and
>     traffic)
>
> What ntopng can do:
>
> - Sort network traffic according to many protocols
> - Show network traffic and IPv4/v6 active hosts
> - Store on disk persistent traffic statistics in RRD format
> - Geolocate hosts
> - Discover application protocols by leveraging on nDPI, ntop’s DPI
>     framework
> - Characterise HTTP traffic by leveraging on characterisation services
>     provided by block.si. ntopng comes with a demo characterisation key, but if you need a permanent one, please mail info@block.si
> - Show IP traffic distribution among the various protocols
> - Analyse IP traffic and sort it according to the source/destination
> - Display IP Traffic Subnet matrix (who’s talking to who?)
> - Report IP protocol usage sorted by protocol type
> - Act as a NetFlow/sFlow collector for flows generated by routers (e.g.
>     Cisco and Juniper) or switches (e.g. Foundry Networks) when used together
>         with nProbe
> - Produce HTML5/AJAX network traffic statistics

See screenshots and documentation on official website (https://www.ntop.org/) .

Install it with:

```
sudo apt install ntopng
```